# simplify expression with Dirac delta

Tags: dirac-delta

I have the following expression I would like to simplify:

$(\frac{x}{y} + \frac{y}{x} )\delta(\sqrt{\frac{xy}{4z}}) $

It should be possible to simplify this but I am wondering what to do as there is no integration there.

Thanks

Comment: What is the origin of this question ?

Comment: sorry I now know that x >0 and y>0. I suppose that means the function is just 0. Thanks!

Comment: Origin is a particle being fired at a potential, x and y are proxies for momenta

Comment: No, these conditions do not mean that you can replace $\delta$ by $0$...

Comment: really OK, I entered the above expression into Wolfram alpha. It said if x and y >0 the function is 0

Comment: WA will say you the same thing for ordinary $\delta$. Don't trust blindly WA especially on these subtle things...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105957/discussion-between-samcro-and-jean-marie).

Comment: Sorry, I have no time for a chat at present. But hopefully tomorrow. Meanwhile,  see this excellent document (https://www.reed.edu/physics/faculty/wheeler/documents/Miscellaneous%20Math/Delta%20Functions/Simplified%20Dirac%20Delta.pdf) in particular its relationship (13)